# What is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions argument in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate

In the AppDelegate -> application function, what is the meaning of the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"? Is it a function being passed to the application method?

Comment: you can get some information from here: http://nshipster.com/launch-options/. or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Have you ever read the `UIApplicationDelegate` documentation? Everything is described there. Easy access is `Quick Help` or ⌥-click on the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate is a protocol. You need to provide an object to the system that conforms to that protocol and serves as the app delegate. The system calls various methods of the app delegate, including the `application :didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

The (Objective-C) method signature looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Do a search in the Xcode docs on "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" to read about it.

So to answer your question, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is a method/function, not an "argument".

The system may pass in a dictionary with information about how the app was launched. (From a local notification, a request to open a file, a Core Location region notification, etc.) The Xcode docs have more information.